# Why is my Provider not updating my index? in my second widget?

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-provider, riverpod, flutter-state

I'm using Riverpod to try and update the index in two different widget, it works fine in the first one but nothing happen in the second one, can someone explain me why? It looks like the second widget doesn't not change/receive the info of the index of the continent..

Provider :

```
final indexProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 2);
```

changing state of the provider :

```
void nextIndex() {
    setState(() {
      ref.read(indexProvider.notifier).state += 1;
    });
```

Where it works :

```
children: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                //cotinent previous
                              },
                              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_left_sharp)),
                          Text(continent[ref.read(indexProvider)]),
                          ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                nextIndex();
                                //continent next
                              },
                              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right_sharp))
                        ],
```

Where it doesn't :

```
 ShowByContinent(
                      continent: continent[ref.read(indexProvider)],
                    )
```

```
class _ShowByContinentState extends ConsumerState<ShowByContinent> {
  List continentCountry = [];
  var continentIndex;
  showByContinent() {
    countries_info.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value["continent"] == continent[ref.read(indexProvider)]) {
        continentCountry.addAll(key.split(","));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showByContinent();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: continentCountry.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              crossAxisSpacing: 3,
              mainAxisSpacing: 3,
              childAspectRatio: 5),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 3, color: splashBackground),
                color: purpleList,
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 10,
              child: Text(continentCountry[index], style: setColors()),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the official riverpod documentation https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading

> ref.watch is used inside the build method of a widget or inside the
> body of a provider to have the widget/provider listen to a provider.
>
> The ref.read method is a way to obtain the state of a provider without
> listening to it.
>
> It is commonly used inside functions triggered by user interactions.
> For example, we can use ref.read to increment a counter when a user
> clicks a button:

Always prefer to use `ref.watch` inside the `build` method so it will listen to changes of provider.

Your first widget is updated only because you are using `setState`. Remove the `setState` and change `ref.read(indexProvider)` inside `build` to `ref.watch(indexProvider)`.

```
void nextIndex() {
    ref.read(indexProvider.notifier).state += 1;
  };

Text(continent[ref.watch(indexProvider)]),

ShowByContinent(
  continent: continent[ref.watch(indexProvider)],
)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but nothing changes. It's still stuck the same way it was.. Any idea why? I'm confused! Tried to follow the doc and see if I made a similar mistake somewhere else but couldn't find one

Can it come from the other widget?

Comment: Move `showByContinent` inside `build` and check whether this method works correctly, as there is no information about `countries_info` and `continent`, I am not sure whether it works.